# Achieve same sort result in Chrome as other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Chrome shows a different sort result from other browsers - with Firefox and Edge showing the desired result.

How to achieve the same result with Chrome?

I tried, but not working, with:

```
$(function(){
    var order = $('.files').find('.first','.second').sort(sortMe);
    $('.files').append(order);
    });

    function sortMe(a, b) {
    return a.first < b.second;
    }
```

The desired result... and the default in Firefox and other browsers is:

```
<div class="file-container">
     <div class="files">
           <div class="first">content</div>
           <div class="first">content</div>
           <div class="second">content</div>
           <div class="second">content</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Chrome returns

```
<div class="file-container">
     <div class="files">
           <div class="first">content</div>
           <div class="second">content</div>
           <div class="second">content</div>
           <div class="first">content</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the comparison between `a` and `b`?

Comment: Your sort function is a little messed up.  It compares undefined to undefined.  The fact that any browser gives you a result you like is chance.

Comment: the class names, where a.first is supposed to be in front of b.second

Comment: The sort function is an attempt at a fix, it does not give the result in the other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Selector at `.find('.first','.second')` is not correct, where second parameter should log an error `Unexpected identifier`, try adjusting to `.find('.first, .second')` without terminating string and including a literal comma `,` character which would pass two parameters, instead of single selector string, comparing `a.dataset -`b.dataset`, where`data-*` attributes have 0-based indexing from 0-n.

You can add `data-*` attribute at elements for comparison function.

```js
    $(function(){
      var order = $('.files').find('.first, .second').sort(sortMe);
      should be$('.files').append(order);
    });

    function sortMe(a, b) {
      console.log(a.dataset)
    return +a.dataset.order - +b.dataset.order;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-container">
     <div class="files">
           <div data-order="0" class="first">first content</div>
           <div data-order="1" class="second">second content</div>
           <div data-order="1" class="second">second content</div>
           <div data-order="0" class="first">first content</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem with jquery, but typically when different test data added to site Chrome returned expected result each time so code not needed this time...

```js
var array = ['first', 'second'];

$.each(array,function(index,value){
   $('.files').append($('.'+value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-container">
   <div class="files">
     <div class="first">content for 1.1</div>
     <div class="second">content for 2.1</div>
     <div class="second">content for 2.2</div>
     <div class="first">content for 1.2</div>
     <div class="first">content for 1.3</div>
     <div class="second">content for 2.2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```